# Why does JSON parsing not fail on the first character for strings starting with "t"?

Tags: javascript, json

I'll try to clarify what I mean as quickly as possible.

```
JSON.parse("te")
VM297:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

JSON.parse("ce")
VM342:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

As you can see, the parsing fails at position 0 for the string "ce" and at position 1 for the string "te". This means that the parser believes that there is some legal JSON that starts with the character "t". Does anybody know what that would be? Or why the parser fails a character later for t?

Comment: What environment is that?

Comment: @Pointy V8 specific

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes so it seems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keyword `true` starts with "t". Thus until the parser sees the "e", it doesn't know the syntax is invalid.

The error is somewhat fascinating because it reports "e" as being a *token*, which is not the way I'd implement a JSON parser. That seems to be a Node/V8 thing, as Firefox rejects the whole token starting from position 1 (the "t").

You can double-check this answer by trying `JSON.parse("nulp")`; Node errors on the "p".

Comment: I'm thinking they thought it as a lexical token.

Comment: @ChaosPandion true, it could just be the way the error message is worded. Firefox does not behave that way fwiw.

Comment: @ChaosPandion or maybe they use a PEG parser, which would be a little weird but JSON is so simple that maybe they found that to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

The full JSON syntax is as follows:

```
JSON = null
    or true or false
    or JSONNumber
    or JSONString
    or JSONObject
    or JSONArray
```

so the compiler will deal with `t`, `n` , `f` as a valid start for a JSON string.
for more information check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse